# javafx - MediaException: PLAYBACK_HALTED : DirectSoundCreate: (NULL)

Tags: javafx, media-player, multimedia, directsound

I wanto to play a mp4 video inside of my java application. The software is running fine on my main PC where a sound card is installed. But on another PC with no sound device at all, this is the content of the player.getError:

```
MediaException: PLAYBACK_HALTED : DirectSoundCreate: (NULL)
```

This is a part of the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.File;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Mixer.Info;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;

Media m = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(m);
MediaView viewer = new MediaView(player);
             
player.setAutoPlay(true);
player.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
player.setOnError(()->Logging.getLogger().log("MediaPlayer setOnError: " + player.getError().toString(),Message.MESSAGE));
```

I can provide more code, if necessary. Once before I provided too much code and got bad comments about that.

My questions, how can I configure javaFX media player or one of it's components to run the video without a sound device. There must be something to configure. But I do not know.

Edit:

I was checking the versions of javafx on both PCs:

```
System.out.print(com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion());
```

8.0.311-b11 (Office PC where the code is working)

8.0.201-b08 (Shopfloor PC where the code is not working)

Edit:

I have installed a virtual sound card on the shopfloor PC. The error message disappeared. But no video is playing. No error message is showing. No exception is showing.

I need to get in contact with out MES supplier, because my java code on the shopfloor PC is running inside of a MES system.

(MES = Manufacturing Execution System)

Comment: _I can provide more code, if necessary. Once before I provided too much code and got bad comments about that._ There are no previous questions posted by you visible, so assuming only: the suggestion probably way to provide a [mcve] - be sure to read that help page! - which is mandatory for debugging questions and which you fail to provide here again ;) That said: _But on another PC with no sound device at all_ wondering what you expect to happen if there is no hardware to support the player?

Comment: Hello dear cleopatra, I don't want to play audio, I only want to play video without sound. The windows media player is running my test video on this PC (without sound device), too. So it must be possible, to tell the javafx media player to run my test video without a sound device and without an error. But how?

Comment: What version of JavaFX are you using?  Have you tried the latest? (17.0.2 at the time I write this)

Comment: Your import statements indicate you are using other (non-JavaFX) APIs to access audio features.  Could these be conflicting?

Comment: Consider removing the audio from your media file if you don't need the audio. See also this bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173619

Comment: You are mixing Swing and JavaFX, which is normally not recommended, but is probably ok here to add media capabilities to an existing Swing application.  Make sure that when you mix them, that all threading rules are strictly obeyed, otherwise strange, unpredictable things can occur.